Most standard method to generate hypotheses, auto-select the best, then manually curate the best
I have been trying to do something like this forever. I would really appreciate someone directing me to the standard mathematics of this (before I try to implement it in programming).
Imagine you have two collections of text. They’ve been chosen to represent two different “discourses”. The goal is to find what aspects of “form” or “structure” they share (to investigate the hypothesis that “they have similar form”).
I think the technique I am interested in is “symbolic regression”, though I’ve never known why it’s called that. My way of describing it is, you enumerate a sequence of “hypotheses”. A hypothesis has to be scored in terms of how well it explains the data. For example, consider the hypothesis “the character ‘t’ is followed by the character ‘.’” You might find this hypothesis confirmed 20% of the time, in the data.
You enumerate all possible zeroth-order hypotheses and assign their accuracy score. Next, you generate first-order hypotheses. For example, imagine if the hypothesis “a period is followed by a space” was the highest scoring hypothesis in the first round. Imagine there is a different hypothesis, “the set containing characters ‘i’ and ‘I’ (form a unit of some kind - treat them as interchangeable)”. Through higher-order hypotheses, eventually, the algorithm discovers the hypotheses that the set of all capital letters is a set which scores extremely highly in the hypothesis, “a period and a space are followed by an element of (the set of capital letters)”.
This process continues. It constructs higher-order categories - eventually, words, then, nouns, then grammar rules in terms of nouns.
It does this by ordering the current hypotheses by their score, so it checks the better hypotheses first. Then, it forms new higher-order hypotheses built out of the previous hypotheses.
These hypotheses should amount to being human readable. That way, the human can interfere and choose which hypotheses to reject, because they don’t want the algorithm to focus on those features. They can choose the features the model discovers that they want to serve as a kind of analytical function of the data.
I just need a very standard mathematical presentation of this so I can get my first handhold into statistical learning techniques like this. Can anyone draw up the standard mathematics of such a technique? Thanks hugely.

I ask for some help from Claude 3 Opus. Here is some of what it said, that I find relevant:

Here's a more formal mathematical presentation of the hypothesis
generation and selection process:
Let X be the set of all possible text strings over a finite alphabet
Σ. Let D1 and D2 be two subsets of X, representing the two collections
of text being analyzed.
Define a hypothesis space H, where each hypothesis h ∈ H is a function
h: X → {0, 1}, representing a pattern or rule that maps text strings
to binary labels (1 if the string satisfies the pattern, 0 otherwise).
Define a scoring function s: H → ℝ that maps each hypothesis to a
real-valued score indicating how well it fits the observed data in D1
and D2. For example, a simple scoring function could be the accuracy
of the hypothesis:
s(h) = (∑x∈D1 h(x) + ∑x∈D2 h(x)) / (|D1| + |D2|)
The hypothesis generation and selection process can be defined as
follows:
Initialize H0 to a set of base hypotheses (e.g., simple character or
word patterns).
For t = 1, 2, ..., T:

Generate a new set of hypotheses Ht by combining or modifying hypotheses in Ht-1.
Calculate scores s(h) for each h ∈ Ht.
Select a subset of hypotheses Ht* ⊆ Ht based on their scores, e.g., Ht* = {h ∈ Ht: s(h) ≥ τ} for some threshold τ.
(Optional) Manually curate Ht* to obtain a final set of hypotheses Ht'.

The hypothesis space H and the generation process in step 1 can be
formalized using concepts from formal language theory and grammar
induction. For example, H could be defined as the set of all regular
expressions over Σ, and the generation process could involve applying
regular expression operators (concatenation, alternation, Kleene star,
etc.) to elements of Ht-1.
Alternatively, H could be defined using a context-free grammar G, and
the generation process could involve applying production rules from G
to elements of Ht-1.
The selection process in step 3 can be seen as a form of feature
selection or model selection, where the goal is to identify a subset
of hypotheses that best explain the observed data according to some
criterion (e.g., accuracy, information gain, minimum description
length).


Another concept that seems relevant is FOIL, but FOIL is first-order. Can we go higher, to n-order?
